# Select all Silverlight DataGrid cell text on cell entry

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, textbox, selectall

I have a DataGrid in SL4 with a simple DataGridTextColumn columns.

I've tried a number of different methods to select all the text in a DataGridCell as soon as the cell changes to an editable TextBox.

The code below was my last attempt.

Inspecting the TextBox in debug shows that the SelectedText property is equal to the Text property. So the problem isn't the TextBox. It seems something is deselecting the text later on.

```
public void PreparingCellForEdit(DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
        {
            textBox.GotFocus += (s, e2) =>
                {
                    {
                        textBox.SelectAll();
                    }
                };
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to keep the text selected and display the TextBox with the selected text to the user?

P.S. I am using Cliburn.Micro to attach the PreparingCellForEdit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat of solution is to force focus to the `TextBox` after attaching to the `GotFocus` event.

Like this:

```
    public void PreparingCellForEdit(DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.GotFocus += (s, e2) => textBox.SelectAll();
            textBox.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What works better for me is the following:

```
public void PreparingCellForEdit(DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textBox.SelectAll());
    }
}
```